# Xarray / Dask - Compute the highest temperature for every coordinate

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, grib, era5

I have a 17GB GRIB file containing temperature ([t2m](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=form)) data for every hour of year 2020. The dimensions of Dataset are `longitude`, `latitude`, and `time`.

My goal is to compute the highest temperature for every coordinate (lon,lat) in data for the whole year. I can load the file fine using Xarray, though it takes 4-5 minutes:

```py
import xarray as xr
xarray_dataset = xr.open_dataset('cds/2020_hourly_t2m.grib', engine='cfgrib')
```

But calling [`xarray.Dataset.max()`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.max.html) crashes the Google Colab session. Which is probably because it requires more than the available memory.

So, I probably need to use Dask to load data in chunks and make computations on those chunks and aggregate the results. I'm new to Dask and finding it difficult to read climate Dataset file using Dask.Array APIs in chunks. I've tried `dask.array.from_array( xarray_dataset.to_array() )` but this too crashes the session.

My question is, how should I read this 17GB GRIB file in chunks using Dask and compute the maximum temperature for the whole year for every lon,lat pair in dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xarray` has `dask`-integration, which is activated when `chunks` kwarg is provided. The following should obviate the need to load the dataset in memory:

```py
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("cds/2020_hourly_t2m.grib", engine="cfgrib", chunks="auto")

test_lazy = ds.max()  # this is lazy
test_result = test_lazy.compute()  # actual result
```

Note the requirement to `.compute()` on the `ds.max()`. This is because operating on chunks will give lazy results that will be computed only when requested explicitly, see [this tutorial](https://tutorial.dask.org/01x_lazy.html).

Comment: Thanks, also: How do I calculate max temperature for the whole year for each of the 1,038,240 (i.e. 1440x721) lon,lat coordinate pairs separately? `ds.max(dim=['longitude', 'latitude'])` ?

Comment: That's right, @eMad! [reference](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.max.html)

Comment: I just found that `ds.max(dim=['time'])` gives the result I need. After ~10 hours of computation